# ggplot geom_area distribution very different than identical geom_histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's plot some histograms from the diamond data set.

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(diamonds, aes(price)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 50) + 
  facet_wrap(~ cut)
```

[image: Capture_A.png]

I can use the same data and plot it as a `geom_area` and the distributions totally change. If you look at the faceted plot above the "fair", or "good" distributions are barely a blip for their respective facets. Look at the "fair" and "good" distributions on the `geom_area` below and they're the largest mountains on the chart. What went wrong? Both are *counts*, not *density*. Shouldn't the distributions look identical? How do I make the `geom_area` distributions identical to the `geom_histogram` distributions?

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(price, fill = cut)) +
  geom_area(bins = 50, stat = "bin")
```

[image: Capture_B.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The geom_area() function show cumulative values. Only the part with the collour is the count for the specific factor. If you use the following code, you will get simmilar results that you obttained with the histograms.

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(price, fill = cut)) +
      geom_area(bins = 50, stat = "bin") + facet_wrap(~cut)
```

I guess you are looking for geom_density.

Try:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(price, fill = cut)) +
     geom_density(bins = 50, stat = "bin", alpha = 0.3)
```

Answer (score 4):

I think because `geom_area()` stacks the distributions. If you facet also `geom_area()` you have the same result:

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(diamonds, aes(price)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 50) + 
  facet_wrap(~ cut)

ggplot(diamonds, aes(price)) +
  geom_area(bins = 50, stat = "bin") + 
  facet_wrap(~ cut)
```

[image]

[image]

The best proof is given by this:

```
# Take only one facet <- cut
diam <- diamonds[which(diamonds$cut=='Ideal'),]

ggplot(diam, aes(price)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 50) + 
  facet_wrap(~ cut)


ggplot(diam, aes(price)) +
  geom_area(bins = 50, stat = "bin") + 
  facet_wrap(~ cut)
```